# How to find all classes of a particular interface within an assembly in .net

Tags: .net, design-patterns, reflection, interface, class

I have a scenario whereby I want n amount of classes to look at the same data and decide if any work needs to be done. Work is done by a team, and multiple teams can work on the data at the same time. I was thinking of creating a class for every team that would implement the CreateWork interface. All CreateWork classes must have their say. At the moment there are only a few but in the future there will be many more.

Sudo code for my planned solution

```
For each CreateWork class in assembly
    class.CheckAndCreateWork(dataIn,returnedCollectionOfWorkToBeDone)
Next
```

Is there a design pattern that can accomplish this in an elegant way? Seems a bit messy to loop round every class in the assembly.

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Get all the types defined in the assembly by using [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx). To obtain a reference for the asembly your code is running on, use [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx).
2. For each type, check if it implements the desired interface by using [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28VS.71%29.aspx).
3. For each appropriate type, create a instance by using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

It would be approximately like this (not tested):

```
foreach(var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()) {
    if(typeof(ITheInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
        var theInstance=(ITheInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        //do something with theInstance
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. I *believe* that `IsAssignableFrom` is slower then `GetInterfaces().Contains(type)` (which only works for interfaces). But I might be wrong.

Comment: I generally prefer IsAssignableFrom because it covers a broad scope than just interface implementations, for example it can tell you if class A inherits from class B.

Comment: IsAssignableFrom is the way to go, GetInterfaces returns the interfaces defined on the current type only, but that doesn't check interface inheritance (IBar : IFoo). csc simplifies that by emitting all the interface chain on the type, but not all compilers do that.

Comment: Might want to add && type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null in the if statement to avoid getting the actual interface as well.  You won't be able to instantiate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard plugin task. There are many implementations out there. If you have already loaded your assemlby, finding types you are interested in is easy - you need to use method `assemlby.GetExportedTypes()` and `Activator.CreateInstance()` (provided you have parameterless constructor - otherwise you may wish to use container to inject dependencies and build up your worker instances)

For simple case this is sufficient:

```
var workerTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && typeof(IWorker).IsAssignableFrom(t));

foreach (var type in workerTypes)
{
    var worker = (IWorker)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    worker.CheckAndCreateWork("Work");
}
```

Getting and loading assemlby is another topic. You can either load in run-time using `Assemlby.LoadFrom()` or link them statically to your application and use something like this:

```
var assembly = typeof(SomeClassInTargetAssembly).Assembly;
```

Dynamic loading may be done by enumerating through all the ***.dll** files in a specific directory (for example, `./plugins`) like this:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(PluginsFolder, "*.dll"))
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
    var workerTypes = GetWorkerTypes(assembly);
    RunWorkers(workerTypes);
}
```

You may want to separate processes of loading and running workers to avoid loading worker types multiple times (in case you need to run workers more than once during application life time)